# AVR PWM output delay before start

Tags: avr, pwm, timer, atmel

I'm using an [ATtiny85](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY85.aspx) to generate a PWM output (using Timer0 in OCR mode), and this PWM output is being switched on and off at regular intervals. I am finding that when switching on the PWM output, there is a delay before it actually starts outputting.

Look at the screenshot below, the green line shows the state I am putting the PWM into (either on or off via TCCR1) and yet there is a delay of what looks like one full cycle before it starts. I've tried also resetting TCNT0 to 0, but this had no effect.

[image]

(Timebase is 20 µs.)

```
SET(DDRB, PB1);
SET(DDRB, PB2);

// Set up PWM for 460 kHz with 8 MHz clock
TCCR1 = (1<<PWM1A) | (1<<COM1A1) | (1<<COM1A0) | (1<<CS10); // Prescaler = none;
GTCCR = (1<<FOC1A);
OCR1A = 9; // 460.750 kHz
OCR1C = 18;

#define BIT_DELAY ((1000000/38400))

while(1) {
    SET(TCCR1, PWM1A);
    SET(PORTB, PB2);
    _delay_us(BIT_DELAY);
    CLR(TCCR1, PWM1A);
    CLR(PORTB, PB2);
    _delay_us(BIT_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet

Comment: yep added, thanks!  One pin is the green and the other is the timer output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the PWM mode of TIMER1 does *not* stop `TCNT` from counting - it only stops the PWM from being output.

So when you disable the output using `CLR(TCCR1, PWM1A)`, `TCNT1` keeps merrily counting along and does *not* reset to `0` when it hits `OCR1C` since it is not in PWM mode anymore. It runs right past `OCR1C` and will keep on counting up to `255` when it rolls over.

The delay you are seeing is the time it take `TCNT1` to count from where ever it happens to be when you enable PWM mode back to `OCR1C`, at which time it will reset to `0` and start doing a normal PWM cycle.

One way to control when the PWM cycle starts after you enable PWM mode is to preload the counter such that it will not have to do a wrap around before starting the normal PWM compare points in  `OCR1A` and then `OCR1C`. For example...

```
    while(1) {
        TCNT1=254;
        SET(TCCR1, PWM1A);
        SET(PORTB, PB2);
        _delay_us(BIT_DELAY);
        CLR(TCCR1, PWM1A);
        CLR(PORTB, PB2);
        _delay_us(BIT_DELAY);
    }
```

... generates this waveform...

[image]

Note that this approach seems like a hack to me and that there are probably better ways to gate the PWM signal that would more straightforward, but the best choice would depend on your application.

Comment: thanks.  Would have never noticed the ocr1c compare was being disabled too!